# Is it safe if a template contains virtual function?

Tags: c++, virtual

Early binding for template and late binding for virtual function. Therefore, is it safe if a template contains virtual function?

```
template<typename T> 
class base {
public:
    T data;
    virtual void fn(T t){}
};
```

Comment: Do you expect a problem with that? How would you write a program that checks to see whether it works properly? What happens when you run that program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is completely safe. Once you instantiate the class template, it becomes normal class just like other classes.

```
template<typename T> 
class base {
public:
    T data;
    virtual void fn(T t){}
};


class derived : base<int> {
public:
    virtual void fn(int t){} //override
};

base<int> *pBase = new derived();
pBase->fn(10); //calls derived::fn()
```

I would also like to point out that while it is allowed virtual function in a class template, it is not allowed virtual function template inside a class (as shown below):

```
class A
{
   template<typename T>
   virtual void f(); //error: virtual function template is not allowed
};
```

Comment: how is it a virtual function template ?

Comment: @krammer: Because it is a function template and it is declared with `virtual` keyword, that is why it is a virtual function template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite safe. You'd use it by having a class derive from it:

```
class derived : public base<int> {
    virtual void fn(int) { std::cout << "derived"; }
};
```

Of course, if it contains any other virtual functions (i.e., is intended to be used as a base class) you *generally* want to make the dtor virtual as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safety concern associated with `virtual` function inside a `template` class. It is as good as, having a `virtual` function inside a normal `class`.